# Find the value of a?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, sequences-and-series

Let $a$ and $b$ be  two positive  numbers such that $a\gt b$. Let $G$ be the geometric mean of $a$ and $b$ (that is, $G=\sqrt{ab}$), and $H$ be the Harmonic mean of $a$ and $b$, that is, $$H = \frac{2}{\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}} = \frac{2ab}{a+b}.$$

If $4G = 5H$, what is the value of $a$?

Comment: I tried to solve it .But after solving equation becomes 4a^2 + 4b^2 = 25ab.

Comment: Not sure exactly what you're looking for, but $4a^2+4b^2=25ab$ could be considered a quadratic in $a$, so you could solve for $a$ that way in terms of $b$.

Comment: I think the OP hasn't put in efforts in solving. Someone please close the question.

Comment: @AbhishekParab: Closing the question 10 minutes after it has been posted by a relatively new user (2 days in) is rather harsh. Explaining what to do to improve the question is a rather better course.

Comment: @Abhishek Parab: You don't know that and we don't close questions for that reason anyway. // anna: The equation should entail $4(a+b)^2=25ab$, which is slightly different from what you have.

Comment: @Arturo thanks. I need some help. Can u give me some good link where i can learn to write in latex.I am new and i have never wrote in latex.

Comment: This has become a duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/112764/find-the-value-of-a so voting to close

Comment: @Ross Both are same.

Comment: @Ross: I think you are linking to the wrong question... your link is *this* question.

Comment: @anna: [This has been addressed](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/934/where-is-the-latex-reference-please).

Comment: To all involved, I cleaned up the comments a bit after some of the edits obsoleted them. @anna: LaTeX allows for prettification of the expressions, but if you are only writing arithmetic expressions, you can hit the ground running by just typing the expression as you would on a graphing calculator and enclosing them in dollar signs (and stick to the convention that juxtaposed symbols are multiplied, it takes a little bit of getting used to that putting `\times` between `$` signs give $\times$). It may not be pretty, but it will be understandable (provided you use sufficient parentheses).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Harmonic Mean of $a$ and $b$ is
$$\frac{2}{\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}} = \frac{2ab}{a+b}.$$
The Geometric Mean of $a$ and $b$ is
$$\sqrt{ab}.$$
So, to state the problem you have in a way that would be actually intelligible would be:

> Let $a$ and $b$ be positive numbers such that $a\gt b$; assume that
>   $$4\times\text{geometric-mean(a,b)} = 4\sqrt{ab} = 5\left(\frac{2ab}{a+b}\right) = 5\times\text{harmonic-mean}(a,b).$$
>   What is the value of $a$?

We have
$$\begin{align*}
4\sqrt{ab} &= \frac{10ab}{a+b}\\
4(a+b) &= \frac{10ab}{\sqrt{ab}}\\
2(a+b) &= 5\sqrt{ab}\\
4(a+b)^2 &= 25ab\\
4a^2 + 8ab + 4b^2 &= 25ab\\
4a^2 -17ab + 4b^2 &=0.
\end{align*}$$
You can view this as a quadratic equation in $a$; the solutions are given by
$$\frac{17b - \sqrt{(17b)^2 - 64b^2}}{8} = \frac{17b-\sqrt{225b^2}}{8} = \frac{17b-15b}{8} = \frac{b}{4}$$
(which is impossible since $a\gt b$) and
$$\frac{17b + \sqrt{(17b)^2 - 64b^2}}{8} = \frac{17b + \sqrt{225b^2}}{8} = \frac{32b}{8} = 4b.$$
So the answer is that $a$ must be $4b$.

You can verify this works: the Geometric Mean of $b$ and $4b$ is $\sqrt{4b^2} = 2b$; the Harmonic mean is 
$$\frac{2(4b)b}{4b+b} = \frac{8b^2}{5b} = \frac{8b}{5}.$$
And 
$$4(2b) = 5\left(\frac{8b}{5}\right).$$

Comment: Thanks Arturo. I did not think of getting the roots using Discriminant. thank you..:)

Comment: @anna: You also did your algebra incorrectly, since you went from $2(a+b) = 5\sqrt{ab}$ to $4(a^2+b^2)=25ab$; that's wrong, because $(a+b)^2\neq a^2+b^2$.

Answer (score 0):

According to the given information we have,
$$4\sqrt{ab} = 5(\frac{2ab}{a+b})$$

$$(a+b) =\frac{5}{2}\sqrt{ab})$$

$$\sqrt{\frac{a}{b}}+\sqrt{\frac{b}{a}} = \frac{5}{2}$$

Let , $t$ $ =$ $\sqrt{\frac{a}{b}}$

$$[t+\frac{1}{t}=\frac{5}{2}].....................Eq(1)$$

*A clever person will immediately infer that* $t=\frac{1}{2}$

*But if its a subjective question we have to justify that also, so*

$$({t+\frac{1}{t}})^2=\frac{25}{4}$$

$$t^2 +\frac{1}{t^2} = \frac{17}{4}$$
NOW,
$$(t-\frac{1}{t})^2= t^2+\frac{1}{t^2} -2 =\frac{9}{4}$$

$$[t-\frac{1}{t}=\frac{3}{2}   ]   .....................Eq(2)$$
neglecting the negative value as we know that$ L.H.S.>0$ , since $,t>0$

From Eq(1) and Eq(2) we have $t=4$, hence $a=4b$